# Play a remote audio in an HTML web page in background

Tags: html, url, audio

I want to click on a button and play a sound say MP3 file.
But the problem is that if HTML file and sound file are placed in same directory then it works but if I have to play a sound file located with any other remote URL then it the file cannot be found.

Can anybody suggest what I should do to play a remote audio file?

I got an idea from here: http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone

code:

```
  <html>  
       <head>  
           <title>Your website</title> 
           <script type="text/javascript" src="audio-player.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
               AudioPlayer.setup("player.swf", {width: 290});  
           </script>      
       </head>  
       <body>       
           <p id="audioplayer_1">Alternative content</p>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_1", 
{soundFile: "http://www.otherwebsite.com/play.mp3"});  
           </script>     
       </body>  
   </html>
```

Comment: You should ask those who wrote the flash audio player.

Comment: So your above example doesn't work, even though `play.mp3` exists at that location?

Comment: You're sure that the paths of "player.swf", "audio-player.js" and "your.mp3" are correct? It would be better that you try to write the absolute paths of these files.

Comment: ["player.swf", "audio-player.js"] and "play.mp3 are not at same location. play.mp3 file is placed at any different location not in my domain space.

Comment: www.website.com/path/player.swf and www.website.com/path/audio-player.js and http://www.otherwebsite.com/play.mp3. now how to achieve dat

Comment: But, can you launch "play.mp3" by the url? Probably this file is wrong or corrupted in this location.

Comment: Anyway try to put the absolute path in these files. Before that I recommend you to check the "play.mp3" url.

Comment: @Swati are you 10000% sure the remote URL exists?

Comment: oh i have just given a sample of play.mp3 i have a perfect url wid me

Comment: can anybody provide some help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You're sure that the paths of "player.swf", "audio-player.js" and "your.mp3" are correct? It would be better that you try to write the absolute paths of these files.

```
  <html>  
       <head>  
           <title>Your website</title> 
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.website.com/path/audio-player.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
               AudioPlayer.setup("http://www.website.com/path/player.swf", {width: 290});  
           </script>      
       </head>  
       <body>       
           <p id="audioplayer_1">Alternative content</p>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_1", 
{soundFile: "http://www.otherwebsite.com/play.mp3"});  
           </script>     
       </body>  
   </html>
```

Comment: plz see my comment in question , audio file is not wid me i have its url of different address/url

Answer (score 0):

Flash Player security sanbox can cause such problem. In this case you need to place a crossdomain.xml file (i dont remember exact content of such file) on server where mp3 file is located